# internal server error -- This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server

Tags: php, ajax, shared-hosting

i am using shared hosting and facing this issue. Even though i have changed my ajax requests to smaller one and after each request i am giving timeout but still issue is there. How i can fix it using shared hosting.
**Note:**
`set_time_limit(0);` not working for me.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` aswell, but I doubt you can achieve 0 time limit if it's shared hosting.

Comment: You need to achieve smaller php script to reduce the execution time :)

Comment: i am breaking it to smaller ones. Like if i have 300 records in xlsx file i am processing 15 in one request.. but after processing 45 request times out. i can't generate an event second time to process further records..how i can do it???

Answer (score 3):

After researching a lot of time I found this solution for Litespeed

In `.htaccess` add the following

```
SetEnv noabort 1
SetEnv noconntimeout 1
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
```

[Litespeed Documentation](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:run-without-timeouts)