# How to solve this Request Timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, web-crawler

I built WordPress plugin that crawel data from other wepsite to my wepsite
but when I use it on the plugin it show me that error:

Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>website mass crawler</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <h2 class="inputmanga"> image url:</h2></p>
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <input class="sumbitmanga" name="activated" type="submit" value="Get!">

 </form>

<?php

set_time_limit(500);


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

if (isset($_POST['activated']) && is_admin()){ 

$furl = $_POST['url'];

$res = $client->request('GET', $furl);

$html = ''.$res->getBody();

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $furl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

$manga_urls = $crawler->filter('#content .galleries_overview')->html();

preg_match_all('!<a href="(\/gallery\/(.*?)\/)">!', $manga_urls, $manga_url);

foreach ($manga_url[1] as $key => $murls) {

    $fullr_url = 'https://example.com'.$murls;

    print_r($fullr_url);

    include 'mass-downloader.php';

}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The tools use every $full_url and crawl data from them to my website

How to solve this problem

Comment: Check this response => [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778455/10399628](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59778455/10399628)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the execution time in your php configuration file.

If you dont know where to find your configuration file, put

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

somewhere in your website, open that page, and you will get the location to your configuration file.

open that file, find and edit the following (increase or decrease. 60 is 60 seconds)

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
max_execution_time = 60
```

restart your php